# What does it mean to say "The greater of _ or _"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, differences

I am reading a document, and it is confusing me and want to be certain of the meaning of this sentence:

`OUR COMPANY'S TOTAL LIABILITY TO YOU FOR ACTUAL DAMAGES FOR ANY CAUSE WHATSOEVER WILL BE LIMITED TO THE GREATER OF $500 OR THE AMOUNT PAID BY YOU FOR THE SOFTWARE THAT CAUSED SUCH DAMAGE.`

If the amount paid for the software equals to $200, then the greater will be $500 ?

and If the amount paid for the software equals to $700, then the greater will be $700 ?

Or is it the opposite?

**Question 2:**

Lets say I want to reword the sentence to be:

`... Limited to the greater of $500 or %25 of the amount paid by you for ...`

Any thing grammatically wrong with that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting a legal document, and we are not lawyers.

Comment: @tchrist, the question is about understanding an English-language sentence.  Also,  “we are not lawyers” is not true of all ELU participants.

Comment: @jwpat7: clearly it is, since this is a free site.

Comment: Off topic analysis/interpretation of a text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have understood correctly. If the software cost $200 then the most you could receive would be $500 because 500 is greater than 200.
2. Your sentence looks correct to me, except that that % symbol should be placed after the number, eg. *25%*.

Comment: No. If the software cost $200 (or *any* amount less than $500), the ***most*** you could receive would be $500 *(liability will be **limited** to [blah blah])*. But in principle if you paid $200 for defective software the company might only offer compensation of $100, and the wording of OP's document would not constitute grounds *in itself* for expecting more.

Comment: -1 @FumbleFingers is correct.

Comment: @FumbleFingers good point, and I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

I honestly cannot see where your confusion lies. Your proposed interpretation agrees with mine, and I cannot see any other possible interpretation.